# Grappelli autocomplete fields only work for staff?

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I'm building a site using Django and Grappelli. Due to the nature of the site I've found myself building two "admin" sites - one for true administrators and another cut down site for content creators. After some investigation, I was hoping to use the `is_superuser` for users who have the ability to control the site in its entirety - IT staff and the like, `is_staff` field for staff who administrate the site and add content editors and lastly, users with neither (but have an account) for people who can just edit some content.

To do this, staff and superusers can log into the regular admin site like normal, and there is a manage site which inherits from `admin.py` but removes the `is_staff` restriction.

Unfortunately, I've discovered that the Grappelli foreign key auto complete fields *only* work if a user has the `is_staff` flag set to true.

Has anyone discovered a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

`is_staff` is not designed for this purpose. [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff)

I think using `django.contrib.auth`'s group-permission structure is just for your problem. 
Create two groups in `/admin/auth/group/`. Let's call them: `IT` and `Editor`. Then set their proper permissions.